# compare two numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to compare two 1d numpy arrays for mismatch as follows.
I have this working with partial success.

```
import numpy as np
a= np.array([0,1,2,3,4,13])
b= np.array([0,1,2,3,4,10,11,12])
mis = max( np.sum(~np.isin(b,a)), np.sum(~np.isin(a,b)))
print(mis)
```

output: 3

expected output : 4 ( 13,10,11,12 are mismatches)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you taking the max of the two sums instead of adding the sums? You are only grabbing the missing entries from a single array (the larger one) by doing that, when you clearly want both.

```
mis = np.sum(~np.isin(b,a)) + np.sum(~np.isin(a,b))
```

Comment: I realized sum would do after posting this thanks @David Moreau

Answer (score 2):

Your code would work if you add the `np.sum`:

```
mis = np.sum(~np.isin(b,a)) + np.sum(~np.isin(a,b))
```

However, check out `setxor1d`:

```
np.setxor1d(a,b) 
# out 
# array([10, 11, 12, 13])
```

You can easily get the length then.

Comment: that's pretty slick np.setxor1d  thanks @Quang Hoang